# jQuery Run on Document Ready and then again on Window Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animation on some text at the top of the screen and part way down. To run the animation I have it add a class.

If I have it add the class when the document is ready, then the animation at the top of the page runs right away but so does the animation partway down the page (so we don't see if happen).

If I have it add the class on scroll, then you need to scroll slightly for the animation at the top of the page to run.

So, I have the following code which works how I would like. My question is, is there a way to combine this? It seems very repetitive.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.animateText').each(function(){
  var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
  var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
    $(this).addClass("slide-text");
  }
});  
});
  
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.animateText').each(function(){
   var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
   var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
      $(this).addClass("slide-text");
   }
  });
});
```

I have tried using this but it is the same as if I just used window scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      $('.animateText').each(function(){
         var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
         var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slide-text");
         }
      });
   });
 });
```

Comment: you could encapsulate the logic in a function so that when updating the source code you only need to touch on the function and not 2 separate events

Comment: ^^^ one of the main reasons to have functions is because they are reusable

Comment: I think I am sort of following but could you provide an example?